# How to put new eventhandle on existing buttons c#?

Tags: c#, button, delegates, event-handling

I want to put on existing button new event handle. I have 9 buttons created in form and want to display each name when is clicked on it, but don't want to put on every button message manually.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: Create one event handler for the OnClick event, cast `sender` to `Button` and display the name.  But you'll have to register that event with each button, either in the markup or the code behind.

Comment: if you just google "code behing add event to all buttons" you will find. be sure to add winform / wpf / whatever your using and

Answer (score 1):

You can use the sender propperty of the EventHandler in order to do that. This example uses winforms buttons:

```
SomeButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var button = sender as Button;
     MessageBox.Show(button.Name);
}
```

And then you can add this event to multiple buttons i.e.:

```
button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(SomeButtonClicked);
button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(SomeButtonClicked);
button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(SomeButtonClicked);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can code something like this

```
   private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     ...
     // Assigning on click event, assuming that all your buttons are on the MainForm
     foreach (Control ctrl in Controls) {
        Button btn = ctrl as Button;

        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, btn))
          btn.Click += onButtonClick;
     }
   ...

   // On click itself
   private void onButtonClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
     Button btn = sender as Button;

     String name = btn.Name; // <- Or whichever property of the button you want
   }
```